# Power BI DAX group by , min max for TrxID

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I'm having trouble trying to obtain summary transaction header level data from my line details data.

I have sales item data with a DateTime for each row added to the table. I want to pull the min and max values of this datetime column BY EACH transaction ID.

Hoping to do this in DAX as a virtual table or measure without going to SQL server again.

Thanks for your help

Sample data.

[image]

Desired Result

[image]

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? To show this in a visual, a DAX calculated table, or within the query editor?

Answer (score 0):

I you need a new table created by DAX, use this code:

```
NewTable = ADDCOLUMNS(
SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[TrxID]), 
"MinDateTime", CALCULATE(min('Table'[LineDateTime])), 
"MaxDateTime", CALCULATE(max('Table'[LineDateTime]))
)
```